# Mutex in C# - Synchronization from Unsynchronized Block of Code

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I am writing a progam which downloads games from a website as zip archives and extracts them. Since all games are downloaded to the same location before being extracted I am using a Mutex to prevent race conditions when two downloads are going on at the same time. The issue is that I am getting a System.ApplicationException thrown saying: "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code." Everything I have looked at says that this is caused by freeing a Mutex from a thread that does not own it. However, my code Wait's and Releases the Mutex in the same thread.

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
   mutex.WaitOne();
   await DownloadGameAsync(ug, nvm);
   await ExtractGameAsync(ug, nvm);
   nvm.Action = "Done";
   mutex.ReleaseMutex();
});
```

If I place a breakpoint on the line mutex.ReleaseMutex(); and step over the line it does not cause the exception to be thrown however, removing the breakpoint and running normally causes an exception with every execution.

Should I be approaching this differently (Semaphores) or is my use of async/await causing the issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use thread-affine synchronization primitives (e.g., a `Mutex`) with `async` in the general case. Specifically, your code after the `await` is *not* guaranteed to run on the same thread as the thread that acquired the mutex.

I recommend using `SemaphoreSlim` and its `WaitAsync` method. `SemaphoreSlim` is the only BCL synchronization primitive that is guaranteed to work correctly with `await`. If you need more complex synchronization primitives, Stephen Toub wrote a [series of blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/tags/coordination+data+structures/) on the subject that I extended and included in my [AsyncEx library](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/documentation).